# POP up triggered by a click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to open a popup by clicking on a button.
Please check my below code and tell me why it isn't working.
I am using getreponse popup

http://www.reussirlegmat.com/2499-2/

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">    
  <head>  
    <meta charset="utf-8">    
  </head>    
  <body>       
    <button id="button" >Show it</button>   
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://app.getresponse.com/view_webform_v2.js?u=BaAuE&webforms_id=7152504">{    
  "name": "myuniqueform2"       
}       
    </script>      
    <script>        
      var myform = GRWF2.get('myuniqueform2'),   
          element = document.getElementById('button');   
      element.addEventListener("click", function(){          
        myform.show();        
      });       
    </script>     
  </body>    
</html>
```

Comment: What is that object literal doing in the script with `src` attribute?

Comment: Sorry I am new to coding so I didnt understand what you mean.

Comment: I have used this reference 
https://support.getresponse.com/faq/can-i-trigger-my-pop-over-web-form-with-a-button-or-a-link

Answer (score 1):

On your website, something has put `<p>...</p>` tags around every line of your script.

```
<p><script type="text/javascript" src="https://app.getresponse.com/view_webform_v2.js?u=BaAuE&#038;webforms_id=7152504">{</p>
<p>"name": "myuniqueform2"   </p>
<p>}   </p>
<p></script>   </p>
<p><script>     </p>
<p>var myform = GRWF2.get('myuniqueform2'),</p>
<p>element = document.getElementById('button');</p>
<p>element.addEventListener("click", function(){       </p>
<p>myform.show();     </p>
<p>});   </p>
<p></script> </p>
<p></body></p>
<p></html></p>
```

Those are causing parse errors. Get rid of them.

I have no idea how you did this -- I suspect you edited the code with a word processor and then told it to export to HTML.

Comment: sorry I don't see this in my page source... nor in my editor.. how I am supposed to remove them.. if I dont see them ?

Comment: I see it when I view the DOM in the browser's Developer Tools. Didn't you see all the errors in the console that this caused?

Comment: But you're right, I don't see it in `View Source`. Let me examine some more.

Comment: It looks like you've already fixed it, the popup is working now.

Comment: I still have  aproblem.

Comment: the popup appears even without clicking the button.. 
how can I fix this?

Comment: I don't see that when I go to your test page.

Comment: Please wait for some seconds and you will !

Comment: It looks like that's the normal behavior of their popup form. You can configure the delay in the Layout section of the editing tool.